# What makes fmap work here without an explicit method declaration?

Tags: haskell, functor, instances

One of the exercises in *Real World Haskell*, ch. 24, asks to implement a strictness wrapper around `Control.Concurrent.MVar`. I am doing this, as suggested in the book, by using a `newtype` `MVarS` wrapper to ensure that `evaluate` is applied to whatever arguments get passed to functions such as `newMVar` and `putMVar`.

Now, one of the functions to wrap is `mkWeakMVar`, whose type is `MVar a -> IO () -> IO (Weak (MVar a))`. Assuming that my `MVarS` builder functions implement strictness, I reasoned that for `mkWeakMVar` it would suffice to put `MVarS` in place of its `MVar`s. So I wrote the following:

```
import           Control.Concurrent.MVar
import           System.Mem.Weak

instance Functor Weak

newtype MVarS a = MVarS (MVar a)

mkWeakMVarS :: MVarS a -> IO () -> IO (Weak (MVarS a))
mkWeakMVarS (MVarS mv) x = (fmap . fmap) MVarS (mkWeakMVar mv x)
```

This appears to work, even though GHCi warns that there is no explicit method declaration of `fmap` for `Functor Weak`. But it leaves me intrigued. What makes `fmap` work in this case?

Comment: It can only work if the `fmap` for `Weak` is never called.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

While the above code will typecheck, GHC will crash when attempting to evaluate a value which requires calling upon the missing `fmap` implementation. It'll look a bit like:

```
*** Exception: /Users/tel/tmp/SO.hs:31:10-18: 
    No instance nor default method for class operation GHC.Base.fmap
```

Since this is a rather *catastrophic* and entirely avoidable runtime error it ought to serve as a testament to the importance of `-Wall`.